# Is there a way to "catch" all skipped items on an IN() statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table Like this:

```
 myTable
 -------------------
|Column1 | Column2  |
|--------+----------|
|foo     |bla       |
|bar     |blabla    |
|baz     |blablabla |
|qwe     |blabal    |
 --------+----------
```

Now, in order to search for multiple entries, I am using `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Column1 IN('foo','bar', 'tre', 'gaz', 'hed',...)`. But, this only show all the items that exists in the table and skips all that doesn't match anything in the table.

```
 result:
 -------------------
|Column1 | Column2  |
|--------+----------|
|foo     |bla       |
|bar     |blabla    |
 --------+----------
```

Is there a way in SQL to catch `'tre', 'gaz', 'hed'...` and all the items that are not existing in the table, but is inside the `IN()` clause??

Comment: you can create a dummy table that contain all the row you want and join this table.

Comment: Dummy table, UNION subquery or CTE - depending on the used version.

Comment: If you want to receive the values from your list than the list must be a rowset. The list in WHERE IN is not. Either use subquery (see Popeye's answer) or save your values into temporary table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `not exists` with subquery as follows:

```
select t.col
  from (select 'foo' as col
       union select 'bar'
       union select 'tre'
       union select 'gaz'
       union select 'hed') t
  where not exists (select 1 from myTable m WHERE Column1 = t.col)
```